# How to rotate object with camera three.js

Tags: javascript, camera, three.js, rotation

Hi I am trying to make an abject follow the camera so I could achieve an effect of a rifle viewfinder. I am using OrbitControl. When I check camera.rotation.y it only shows that the range is from -PI/2 to PI/2 while I can rotate camera by 360 degrees. I cannot get my head around it please help!

so far I got there (it is only a part of my code):

```
    pivot = new THREE.Object3D();
    pivot.add(viewfinder);//adding viewfinder as a child of pivot
    scene.add( pivot );
```

and later on

```
    pivot.rotation.y =  camera.rotation.y;
```

this allows to rotate my viewfinder but for some reason it is exactly  by Pi/2 shifted so I deducted it from current camera position and I have this:

```
   pivot.rotation.y =  (camera.rotation.y - (Math.PI/2)) ;
```

and that allows me to rotate viewfinder with camera but only in the range of 180 degrees. How can I rotate it by full 360?
Please help me.
Thak You.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831425/static-object-in-scene-three-js/31835326#31835326) is what you are referring to.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to make the mesh always face to your camera, right? you could use camera matrix to set mesh rotation, `mesh.rotation.setRotationFromMatrix(camera.matrix)`, but be careful if your mesh had a parent entity. or you can use `lookAt()` function, `mesh.lookAt(camera.position)`, either works fine.

Answer (score 1):

THREE JS, I tested this with "PointerLockControls"--
IF you want OBJECT SAME Y ROTATION OF CAMERA :
** you need to do this in animation before renderer.render( scene, camera );**

```
const getCameraRotate = new THREE.Vector3();
        camera.getWorldDirection( getCameraRotate);
        getCameraRotate.y = 0;
        getCameraRotate.add( object.position );
        object.lookAt( getCameraRotate );
```

If you want OBJECT SAME X.Y.Z ROTATION OF CAMERA :

```
       object.rotation.copy(camera.rotation)
```

IF you want object same position to camera :

```
object.position.copy (new THREE.Vector3 (camera.position.x, camera.position.y, camera.position.z));
```

if your object gets the same position as the camera, you certainly wouldn't
see it, because you would be inside, try to change some value, for example

```
new THREE.Vector3 (camera.position.x-5, camera.position .y -5, camera.position.z)
```