# Attach object to camera three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'll like to attach my object on my camera or camera target.

I try with `crosshair.parent = camera;` and this but doesn't work:

```js
//Crosshair
var crosshair = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 5, 5 ), mat_crosshair );
   // place it in the center
var crosshairPercentX = 50;
var crosshairPercentY = 50;
var crosshairPositionX = (crosshairPercentX / 100) * 2 - 1;
var crosshairPositionY = (crosshairPercentY / 100) * 2 - 1;

crosshair.position.x = crosshairPositionX * camera.aspect;
crosshair.position.y = crosshairPositionY;

crosshair.position.z = -0.3;
crosshair.rotation.y = 1.6;

camera.add( crosshair );
scene.add ( crosshair )
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try using pointer lock controls: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/PointerLockControls.js

Comment: how doest it works ? i add the script but nothing change.

Comment: `var controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(camera);
scene.add(controls.getObject());
controls.enabled = true;`

Comment: it returns: THREE.PointerLockControls is not a constructor

Comment: You need to add the library first: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/PointerLockControls.js

Comment: i did it. but it returns this error. i've find this exemple: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webvr_cubes.html   so i had line 73 to 82.. and again nothing

Comment: @Noodle09 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831425/static-object-in-scene-three-js/31835326#31835326

Comment: thx it's works fine !